# Socket messages sent faster then app can receive

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm fairly new to socket programming and not sure about a specific scenario:

Let's say I have a (python) application which has a socket server opened and listening on TCP 127.0.0.1 port 2030.

By using poll_interval, this application can receive and handle 20 messages/second. 
But the 3rd party (that i can't control), sends 40 messages/second.

I've noticed that after a while, the application socket server hangs and can't receive any new connection.

I've checked socket status on my machine:

`ss -pl | grep 2030`

And see that there are hundreds of sockts in `Recv-Q` that are not going away.

```
root@mymachine:~# ss -l | grep 2030
tcp    LISTEN     578      5            127.0.0.1:2030                  *:*
```

Also, i have noticed hundreds of sockets in `close-wait` status:

```
root@mymachine:~# netstat -ton | grep CLOSE_WAIT | grep 2030
tcp      580      0 127.0.0.1:2030          127.0.0.1:34200         CLOSE_WAIT  off (0.00/0/0)
```

Are these related? And if so, how one would protect a socket app from a throughput higher than it supposed to handle?

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, the issue is not that the app can receive only 20 messages/second. It's by design. The question is in general how to protect socket apps from throughput they are not design for.

In any case, i'm sharing some code:

```
socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), SocketHandler)

threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever, kwargs={'poll_interval': 0.002}).start()
```

---

```
class SocketHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

def handle(self):

    data = self.request.recv(1500)

    try:
        decoded = data.decode("utf-8")
        parsed = do_some_parsing()

        if not parsed:
            raise UnreadableMessage("Couldn't parse {}".format(data))

    except UnreadableMessage as e:
        logger.warning(e)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unknown exception occurred when tried to parse message: {]".format(data))

    finally:
        self.request.close()
```

Comment: ``poll_interval`` is the shutdown check interval, not the request handling interval. Can you share *any* code that may help us say why your application is slow?

Comment: In general TCP has a flow control which causes a sender to automatically slow down (and maybe block) if the recipient cannot read the data fast enough. If your server hangs instead of (slowly) reading the data then it has a bug.

Comment: Then i'm probably missing something, please see the added code snippet